# subfolder is not working as a package in python

Tags: python, package, python-import

I have a folder structure as :

```
outer/
   scripts/
      start-emr/
         config/
            conf.yml
         __init__.py
         abc.py
      __init__.py
      pqr.py
   start.py
```

here, you can see, I've a **init**.py file in "scripts" folder and it works as a python package because of **init**.py file and I can import pqr.py file.

But, when I try to import "start-emr" as a package, it is not acting as a package, it is working as a normal folder even if it has a **init**.py file.

from scripts import

does not gives suggestion for pqr.py but not for "start-emr"

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my question.

The problem is with folder having "-" in the name, python does not allow "-" in the package name.